# Reuse react component with functionality changes

Tags: reactjs

I'm developing a common npm package with React's components for later usages in several projects. I've got default snackbar components and one wrapper component that will return a certain snackbar depending on snackbar's type provided to the wrapper's props. Here is my snackbar wrapper's code:

```
const TYPES = {
  [SNACKBAR_TYPES.SUCCESS]: SnackbarSuccess,
  [SNACKBAR_TYPES.ERROR]: SnackbarError,
  [SNACKBAR_TYPES.INFO]: SnackbarInfo,
  [SNACKBAR_TYPES.LOADING]: SnackbarLoading
}

const CustomSnackbars = props => {
  const CustomSnackbar = TYPES[props.snackbarType]

  if (!CustomSnackbar) {
    console.log('Invalid snackbar type was provided')
    return null
  }

  return (
    <CustomSnackbar {...props} />
  )
}
```

This wrapper will be used in projects for creating `CustomSnackbars` container. But here comes one problem that every project will probably define it's own snackbars with it's own snackbar type. And I don't want to put every snackbar that I will have later in my projects to my common module. Is it possible to somehow extend `CustomSnackbars` wrapper from the each projects's side, so this wrapper will have specific to each project's snackbar types in addition to default snackbar types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to pass your additional TYPES by props:

**CustomSnackbars.js (in common library)**

```js
const TYPES = {
  [SNACKBAR_TYPES.SUCCESS]: SnackbarSuccess,
  [SNACKBAR_TYPES.ERROR]: SnackbarError,
  [SNACKBAR_TYPES.INFO]: SnackbarInfo,
  [SNACKBAR_TYPES.LOADING]: SnackbarLoading
}

const CustomSnackbars = props => {
  const enhancedTypes = {...TYPES, ...props.userDefinedTypes};
  const CustomSnackbar = enhancedTypes[props.snackbarType]

  if (!CustomSnackbar) {
    console.log('Invalid snackbar type was provided')
    return null
  }

  return (
    <CustomSnackbar {...props} />
  )
}
```

Moreover, if you do not want to pass these `userDefinedTypes` to props in every instance of `CustomSnackbars` in your consumer project, you can create project specific `CustomSnackbars`, which will just render your common `CustomSnackbars` with userDefinedTypes in props.

**ProjectSpecificCustomSnackbars.js (in your project)**

```js
const PROJECT_SPECIFIC_TYPES = {
  [SNACKBAR_TYPES.PROJECT_SUCCESS]: SnackbarProjectSuccess,
  [SNACKBAR_TYPES.PROJECT_INFO]: SnackbarProjectInfo
}

const ProjectSpecificCustomSnackbars = props => (
  <CustomSnackbars {...props} userDefinedTypes={PROJECT_SPECIFIC_TYPES} />
)
```